# Как получить имя кнопок сгенерированных из списка. Python, Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Как можно получить имена кнопок если я их вывожу через цикл.
в таком случае выводится последнее значение списка

```
from tkinter import *


class Gui(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.build_gui()

    def build_gui(self):
        lis = ['one', 'two', 'three']

        root = Tk()
        root.title('test')
        root.geometry('200x400')

        for i in lis:
            button = Button(root, text=i, command=lambda: self.delete(i))
            button.pack()

        root.mainloop()

    def delete(self, i):
        print(i)


app = Gui()
```

Я понимаю что ткинтер не очень но я пока на нем тренеруюсь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема с пониманием контекста выполнения. Когда вы нажмёте на кнопку, будет выполнена лямбда присвоенная этой кнопке. В момент выполнения этой лямбды цикл будет давно закончен, поэтому переменная цикла будет иметь значение последней итерации. Чтобы передать в лямбду значение той итерации, на которой лямбда создана, надо использовать *замыкание*. Самый простой способ для этого - использовать параметры по умолчанию:

```
for i in lis:
    button = Button(root, text=i, command=lambda i=i: self.delete(i))
```

Comment: спасибо большое