# Tkinter Python. Как можно получить информацию о положении виджета (Button) в grid или номер в массиве, по его состоянию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, grid

Как можно получить информацию о положении виджета (button) в grid по его состоянию или его позицию в массиве, подскажите пожалуйста. Если это возможно, но есть способ проще, расскажите о нем.

Это набросок программы и мне требуется узнать координаты (номер колонки и строки) кнопки, значение которого только что поменяли, либо ее номер в массиве.
Но так как я первый раз работаю с Tk, не хватает знаний для реализации. Подскажите пожалуйста оптимальный способ реализации.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def finish():
    root.destroy()
    print("Закрытие приложения")

btn = []

def creat_btn():
    a = entry1.get()
    b = entry2.get()
    for i in range (1,int(a)+1):
        for j in range(0, int(b)):
            btn.append(Button(text= f"{i - 1} {j}", command=click_button).grid(row=i, column=j, columnspan=1))


clicks = 0

def click_button():
    global clicks
    clicks += 1
    if (clicks == 1):
        print ('1')
    elif (clicks == 2):
        print('2')


root = Tk()
root.title("")

entry1 = ttk.Entry(text = "длинна"#, textvariable = a)
                   )
entry1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=1)
entry2 = ttk.Entry(text = "ширина"#,textvariable = b)
                   )
entry2.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=1)
entry3 = ttk.Entry(text = "шаг"#, textvariable = c)
                   )
entry3.grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=1)

btn1 = ttk.Button(text="зафиксирвать", command = creat_btn)
btn1.grid(row=0, column=3, columnspan=1)


root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", finish)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/858389/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b3%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-python-tkinter?rq=1

Comment: Распечатайте btn у вас там будет список из none, так как вы сохраняете не кнопки, а результат метола grid. Разбейте по разным строкам создание кнопки, ее размещение и ее добавление в список.